# Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync() fires OnAppearing for iOS but not Android when it goes back a page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.shell

I am using the following command to open a new page:

```
OpenPageCmd = new Command<string>(async (route) => await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(route));
```

I am using this command to go back to the page:

```
Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync();
```

OnAppearing is being called in iOS **but not in Android with XF 4.1.0.709244**

Note that I am not using the latest XF as that's causing other known issues that stop the app from working properly.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this. It's a serious problem for me and holding up release of the app.

Comment: Have you tried running that on MainThread?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce this question with XF 4.1.0.709244 ,could you please share a basic demo so that we ca test with it?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think they implemented shell lifecycle until XF 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there was a [bug in XF 4.1](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6486) where the OnAppearing methods was not executing that was [resolved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.2/4.2.0#shell) in XF 4.2. While I understand not being able to update due to other issues that may occur, this may be a case where a choice needs to be made as to which route will be the easier to work around.